# Application design: Central vs Private cache

Tags: go, caching, design-patterns

I am writing some library code in Go, where different modules/packages need to cache their credentials like public keys and authentication tokens.
I have two ideas:

1. Each package will take care of it's own caching.
2. A central cache wrapped over by different implementations of respective packages.

   - There will be an actual cache object holding the key-pairs.
   - Respective implementations for packages will perform operations like get, set and refresh over the cache.
   - Packages will use this implementations.

I am trying to understand pros/cons of both the approaches.

Comment: You may want to look at some caching libraries.  I recommend this one (tho, I wrote it so...): https://github.com/jwells131313/goethe.  It uses the CAR algorithm which performs better than LRU in most cases

Answer (score 0):

The main pros/cons to my mind would be:

1. Private caches have more code duplication
2. Shared cache code likely sacrifices type-safety because you'll have to cache everything as `interface{}`